# Insertion error : java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: java, sql, excel, oracle

I am trying to read one excel sheet and then inserting it to the Database but while doing I am getting the ORA exception but when i manually tried the insert command it was working fine.

Below is the table schema :

```
Name                Null     Type                              
------------------- -------- --------------------------------- 
LANGUAGE            NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)                 
ZONE                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)                 
PRIORITY            NOT NULL NUMBER(20,2)                      
PRODUCT_SEGMENT     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(100 CHAR)                
CUSTOMER_SUBTYPE             VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)                 
MCC                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)                 
MNC                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)                 
CUSTOMER_TYPE       NOT NULL VARCHAR2(5 CHAR)                  
TEMPLATE_WELKOM              VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)                 
TEMPLATE_VOICE               VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)                 
TEMPLATE_VOICE_FREE          VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)                 
TEMPLATE_DATA                VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)                 
TEMPLATE_DATA_FREE           VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)                 
TEMPLATE_CAP                 VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)                 
TEMPLATE_TRAILER             VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)                 
TEMPLATE_PROMO               VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)                 
TEMPLATE_SMS                 VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)                 
SYS_CRE_DATE        NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE 
SYS_UPD_DATE        NOT NULL TIMESTAMP(6) WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE 
TEMPLATE_PULL                VARCHAR2(50 CHAR)
```

Below is the code:

package mosa.common.transaction;

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;

public class InapUnifyPushPull {

    public static String unify_push_pull_insert="INSERT INTO Unify_push_pull_dummy(PRIORITY, PRODUCT_SEGMENT, CUSTOMER_TYPE, CUSTOMER_SUBTYPE, MCC, MNC, ZONE, LANGUAGE, TEMPLATE_PULL, TEMPLATE_WELKOM, TEMPLATE_VOICE, TEMPLATE_SMS, TEMPLATE_VOICE_FREE, TEMPLATE_DATA, TEMPLATE_DATA_FREE, TEMPLATE_CAP, TEMPLATE_PROMO, TEMPLATE_TRAILER, SYS_CRE_DATE, SYS_UPD_DATE) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,sysdate,sysdate);";


    public static Connection GetConeection() throws SQLException{
        Connection con=null;
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");

        con=DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@indsun063:1521:inad1", "M2M", "vodafone");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        return con;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static void InsertData(List sheetData) throws SQLException {
        Connection con=null;
        try {
            con=GetConeection();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int priority=0;
        String productSegment=null;
        String customerType=null;
        String customerSubtype=null;
        String MCC=null;
        String MNC=null;
        String Zone=null;
        String language=null;
        String pull=null;
        String welkom=null;
        String voice=null;
        String sms=null;
        String voiceFree=null;
        String Data=null;
        String DataFree=null;
        String dataCapping=null;
        String Promo=null;
        String Trailer=null;


        for (int i = 1; i < sheetData.size(); i++) {
            List list = (List) sheetData.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                Cell cell = (Cell) list.get(j);

                if(cell.getColumnIndex()==0){
                    if(cell.getCellType()==0){
                        priority=(int)cell.getNumericCellValue();
                    } else {
                        priority=Integer.parseInt(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    }

                } else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==1){
                    if(cell.getCellType()==0){
                        productSegment=String.valueOf((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    } else {
                        productSegment=cell.getStringCellValue();
                    }

                }else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==2){
                    if(cell.getCellType()==0){
                        customerType=String.valueOf((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    } else {
                        customerType=(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    }

                } else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==3){
                    if(cell.getCellType()==0){
                        customerSubtype=String.valueOf((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    } else {
                        customerSubtype=(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    }

                } else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==4){
                    if(cell.getCellType()==0){
                        MCC=String.valueOf((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    } else {
                        MCC=(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    }

                } else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==5){
                    if(cell.getCellType()==0){
                        MNC=String.valueOf((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    } else {
                        MNC=(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    }

                } else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==6){
                    if(cell.getCellType()==0){
                        Zone=String.valueOf((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    } else {
                        Zone=(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    }

                } else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==7){
                    if(cell.getCellType()==0){
                        language=String.valueOf((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    } else {
                        language=(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    }

                } else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==8){
                    if(cell.getCellType()==0){
                        pull=String.valueOf((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    } else {
                        pull=(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    }

                } else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==9){
                    if(cell.getCellType()==0){
                        welkom=String.valueOf((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    } else {
                        welkom=(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    }

                } else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==10){
                    if(cell.getCellType()==0){
                        voice=String.valueOf((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    } else {
                        voice=(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    }

                } else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==11){
                    if(cell.getCellType()==0){
                        sms=String.valueOf((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    } else {
                        sms=(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    }

                } else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==12){
                    if(cell.getCellType()==0){
                        voiceFree=String.valueOf((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    } else {
                        voiceFree=(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    }

                } else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==13){
                    if(cell.getCellType()==0){
                        Data=String.valueOf((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    } else {
                        Data=(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    }

                } else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==14){
                    if(cell.getCellType()==0){
                        DataFree=String.valueOf((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    } else {
                        DataFree=(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    }

                } else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==15){
                    if(cell.getCellType()==0){
                        dataCapping=String.valueOf((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    } else {
                        dataCapping=(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    }

                } else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==16){
                    if(cell.getCellType()==0){
                        Promo=String.valueOf((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    } else {
                        Promo=(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    }

                } else if(cell.getColumnIndex()==17){
                    if(cell.getCellType()==0){
                        Trailer=String.valueOf((int)cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    } else {
                        Trailer=(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    }

                }
            }

                //PreparedStatement stmt;
                try {
                    PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(unify_push_pull_insert);
                    System.out.println(priority +","+productSegment+","+customerType+","+customerSubtype+","+MCC+","+MNC+","+Zone+","+language+","+pull+","+welkom+","+voice+","+sms+","+voiceFree+","+Data+","+DataFree+","+dataCapping+","+Promo+","+Trailer);
                    stmt.setInt(1, priority);
                    stmt.setString(2, productSegment);
                    stmt.setString(3, customerType);
                    stmt.setString(4, customerSubtype);
                    stmt.setString(5, MCC);
                    stmt.setString(6, MNC);
                    stmt.setString(7, Zone);
                    stmt.setString(8, language);
                    stmt.setString(9, pull);
                    stmt.setString(10, welkom);
                    stmt.setString(11, voice);
                    stmt.setString(12, sms);
                    stmt.setString(13, voiceFree);
                    stmt.setString(14, Data);
                    stmt.setString(15, DataFree);
                    stmt.setString(16, dataCapping);
                    stmt.setString(17, Promo);
                    stmt.setString(18, Trailer);
                    stmt.executeUpdate();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.out.println();
                    con.close();
                    con=GetConeection();
                    PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement(unify_push_pull_insert);
                    stmt.setInt(1, priority);
                    stmt.setString(2, productSegment);
                    stmt.setString(3, customerType);
                    stmt.setString(4, customerSubtype);
                    stmt.setString(5, MCC);
                    stmt.setString(6, MNC);
                    stmt.setString(7, Zone);
                    stmt.setString(8, language);
                    stmt.setString(9, pull);
                    stmt.setString(10, welkom);
                    stmt.setString(11, voice);
                    stmt.setString(12, sms);
                    stmt.setString(13, voiceFree);
                    stmt.setString(14, Data);
                    stmt.setString(15, DataFree);
                    stmt.setString(16, dataCapping);
                    stmt.setString(17, Promo);
                    stmt.setString(18, Trailer);
                    stmt.executeUpdate();
                }



            }
        }



}
```

Console Output :

```
No of rows : 95
60000,BUURLANDEN,I,,999,999,BELGIE_DUITSLAND,NL,,,1,1,,1,,,,
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character


    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:213)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:952)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1160)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3285)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3368)
    at mosa.common.transaction.InapUnifyPushPull.InsertData(InapUnifyPushPull.java:213)
    at mosa.common.file.read.main(read.java:83)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the semi-colon in your insert String.

```
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,sysdate,sysdate);";
                                                            ^
```

Remove that and you should be good to go.